# AngularJS forEach compare next index array

Tags: angularjs, foreach, compare

I have a JSON that is returning Objects inside of an array.

I'm using angular.forEach to iterate the data. Each object has a date to which I would like to compare with the next object in the list.

How could this be done?

The snippet below is returning all the dates, I would like to check if the next entry is the same date as the previous. If it is not then compare the two values with Moment.js

So the first [0] and second [1] have the same date, however the third date [2] has "2015-01-03" I need to catch this and compare the two values.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

```js
    $scope.my_data = [
      {
        date: "2015-01-02"
      },
      {
        date: "2015-01-02"
      },
      {
        date: "2015-01-03"
      },
    ];

    angular.forEach($scope.my_data, function(value1, key1) {
      var missing_days = value1.date;
      console.log('missing days', missing_days);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with angular.forEach, just use the provided index to look ahead one place in the original data set

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.my_data = [{
    date: "2015-01-02"
  }, {
    date: "2015-01-02"
  }, {
    date: "2015-01-03"
  }, ];

  angular.forEach($scope.my_data, function(value, key) {
      var missing_days = value.date;
      console.log('missing days', missing_days);
      var nextObject = $scope.my_data[key+1 % $scope.my_data.length];
      console.log(nextObject);
  });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/y4qeNe?p=preview